# Do non-revenue flight tickets incur tax liabilities on the individual who obtained or used the ticket in the United States?

Tags: united-states, benefits, travel, taxable-benefits

Airline employees often have access to so-called non-revenue flight tickets, for themselves or their surroundings. Do non-revenue flight tickets incur tax liabilities on the individual who obtained or used the ticket in the United States? In other words, is it a taxable benefit?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If they book the ticket for free as a benefit to them being airline employees then it is taxed as a fringe benefit based on the value of the ticket.

If they hitch a ride on a flight on a stand-by basis if there's extra space available (i.e.: no guarantees that they'll fly and they only take an empty seat and not a seat reserved specifically for them) then there's no income tax liability.

See [26 CFR 1.132-2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.132-2).